# How to assign value to unchecked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm creating a form with multiple checkboxes and I want to value of the checked checkboxes to be "yes" and the value of unchecked checkboxes to be "no". The site I'm hosting my form on does not let me add the hidden field with the same name and a different value so I have to find script that will add the hidden checkbox on submission and include the value of "no". Currently, when I submit the form the unchecked boxes are recorded as undefined but for data purposes I need it to be filled with "no".

Here is what I found:

```
$(document).ready($("#foo").submit(
  function() {

    // Add an event listener on #foo submit action...
    // For each unchecked checkbox on the form...
    $(this).find($("input:checkbox:not(:checked)")).each(

      // Create a hidden field with the same name as the checkbox and a value of 0
      // You could just as easily use "off", "false", or whatever you want to get
      // when the checkbox is empty.
      function(index) {
        var input = $('<input />');
        input.attr('type', 'hidden');
        input.attr('name', $(this).attr("name")); // Same name as the checkbox
        input.attr('value', "no"); // or 'off', 'false', 'no', whatever

        // append it to the form the checkbox is in just as it's being submitted
        var form = $(this)[0].form;
        $(form).append(input);

      } // end function inside each()
    ); // end each() argument list

    return true; // Don't abort the form submit

  } // end function inside submit()
));
```

Why is the script not working?

Comment: Ypur synthax for ready handler is just wrong, check any basic example. Btw, your indentation is awfull, making your code unreadable

Comment: what does this mean `var form = $(this)[0].form`... forms have a .form property?

Comment: this needs a lot of debugging... would be good to output console messages with values of variables at each point, to see if your functions are even running and if the variables are getting the values you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use this much simpler script. Works perfectly.

```
$('#foo').click(function () {
    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').each( function () {
        var checkbox = $(this);
        if( checkbox.is(':checked')) {
            checkbox.attr('value','yes');
        } else {
            checkbox.after().append(checkbox.clone().attr({type:'hidden', value:'no'}));

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to check out the jQuery API documents

`$(document).ready(function(){});` it takes function callback, which may not needed here.

`$("#foo").submit`takes function callback, which will be called right before the form is submitted.

No need to wrap selector in `$.find`

2. You need to figure out the context of `this`

The `this` in `$(this).attr("name")` is referring the input box

The `this` in `$(this)[0].form` is still the input box

I guess you are trying to get the reference of `forms`. You may use `document.forms`

Comment: I've made edits to the script and I still don't see the desired results: https://jsfiddle.net/gvd1jr0o/1/

Comment: Please let me know your thoughts on the updated script in the fiddle. I'm still not getting a value in the unchecked checkboxes

Comment: Ok, so your script works, thank you! But, something weird is happening. The script only seems to work if I submit the form one time with all boxes unchecked then submit again. Every time I refresh the page the script doesnt work until I submit it once with all unchecked boxes. Why would that happen?

Comment: Is it that we are adding the event listener after the first submission? No when the form is opened?

Comment: @cgrouge i am not sure if i understand what you said. The callback  function will only be callled after you click the submit button and right before submitting the form. The event should be bound when $.submit got executed.

Comment: For some reason when the form is loaded I have to hit the submit button two times in order for the script to begin working. Why would it do this?

Comment: I've captured the process of what I mean. When I submit the form the first time, the unchecked checkboxes give a value of "undefined" - meaning they weren't recorded. But if I submit it again after that, the script begins to work and I get "no" as a value of unchecked checkboxes: https://gfycat.com/HarshWaterloggedKestrel

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the input with $(this). Within the **.each** function $(this) will refer to the checkbox itself.

Comment: I was able to change the input for the each function and I'm still not receiving the "no" value

Comment: you cant sent a no value on an input type checkbox it will be a boolean you have to remove the input type checkbox before submit and replace them by inputs hidden

Comment: you can just replace "append" by "prepend" and I think it will works too

Comment: @bormat unfortunately, I'm still getting the same undefined value. Here is the script edited to your suggestion https://jsfiddle.net/gvd1jr0o/

Answer (score 0):

It isn't normal to have severals input with same name you can put the value directly in checkbox

```
 $(this).find($("input:checkbox:not(:checked)")).each(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).is(':checked') ? "yes" : "no")
 })
```

Comment: note that ternary is useless here because it is only not checked

Comment: I had some success with adding a second field with the same name but the script stopped working. Using your suggestion I'm still not getting a new value for the unchecked checkbox. I only see undefined.

Comment: the value does not appear in attribute if you want it appear replace $(this).val( by $(this).attr('value,

Comment: This solution still is not working for me. I've included the new script here: https://jsfiddle.net/d5tzx391/